# Как проиграть музыку в пайтон?

Tags: python

Мне нужно чтобы человек вписывал в input название музыки и чтобы она врубалась, при этом не скачивая саму музыку.

```py
from tkinter import *

def click():
    name = inp.get()
    #play music

root = Tk()
root.title("Sig Music")
root['bg'] = "black"

inp = Entry().pack()
butt = Button(text="On", command=click).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ну значит она должна быть у человека на устройстве?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй изучить модуль [PYO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcRzJ4mpGFc) и банально написать музыку сразу в python в другом же случае музыка должна быть у тебя на устройстве